# Access data can't be imported to excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to import/export a cell in/to Access. This cell is where my coworkers can input their comments (Cell B29).

Here is the coding I write for exporting the data:

```
rs.Fields("CustomNotes") = Sheets("Main").Range("CUSTOMNOTES")
```

When I save the data into database, the contents in the cell were successfully saved into the database - in a column with long text.

However, when I read the data from the database, the cell is empty and doesn't show anything. Here is the code i write for importing data:

```
Sheets("Main").Range("CUSTOMNOTES") = rsl![CustomNotes]
```

When I do the debugging, rsl![CustomNotes] shows object required..

Can someone please help here? Do I need to add any definition or my variable type is wrong?

[image]

Comment: I assume that `rsl!` is a variable that ties to the table where the `CustomNotes` field is - since you don't show that part of your code. 1) Try `rsl![CustomNotes].Value` 2) Try `Dim s As String | s = rsl![CustomNotes].Value | Sheets("Main").Range("CUSTOMNOTES") = s`

Comment: Thanks, Scott. Will try that. Here is my rsl definition:
 Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM AIF_Summary ORDER BY ID Desc", dbReadOnly)

Comment: Is that field a `Long Text`/`Memo` field? That could be the problem.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman hi scott, i tried both methods and they did not work. When I do the  debugging, the object required disappeared but it doesnt show any value now.. the value of S appears to be "" for Sheets("Main").Range("CUSTOMNOTES") = s

Comment: @braX YES, SIR! It is long text. Don't we need to set it to long text for people put comments (comments include words and numbers)?

Comment: No, it just cant be more than 255 characters... that's the only real difference. Use `Short Text` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Why is Excel even used as database interface?

Comment: @June7 I believe many people are under the impression that "Excel can do anything"

Answer (score 0):

Every time I have seen a problem like this, it was related to the field being a `Long Text`/`Memo` field and changing the field type to `Short Text` has fixed it. Excel has problems with `Long Text` in some cases.

The main difference between a `Short Text` and a `Long Text` field is simply the number of characters can hold (256). They both can store alpha and numeric characters.

Other limitations for `Short Text` are that it cannot hold `Rich Text` information, whereas `Long Text` can. If you are using `Short Text` and need special formatting done, you will need to do that in code instead after you retrieve the data.

Comment: Thanks! Change it to short text made it work!  I am not sure if 256 characters are enough. It should be enough in most cases (does it mean 256 words or letters)? If the character length goes over than that, is there any alternate solution?

Comment: 256 characters, not 256 words. As for an alternate, it really depends on what you plan on doing with it. Why do you need more than 256 characters? If it's just a memo, think to yourself, "is anyone ever going to actually READ something that long?"

Comment: Also, as someone else mentioned, is there a reason you need to use Excel for this? If you truly need to use a `Long Text` field, you may want to consider developing with something like VB.NET instead of Excel. Excel does have some limitations.

Comment: You are right about limitations of excel and i totally agree. It is just that the previous work was all done in excel and i am trying to update and include some new features/functions.  It is not possible for my company to switch to another tool.

Comment: Here comes another question: all the input data cells in my spreadsheet have cell names and they are all input as numbers. There are 7 tabs in my spreadsheet and each tab has 30-40 entries for numbers. In the database, i have a table with one column called "variablevalues". So all values of these cells are saved in this column using VBA. Now the problem is that my coworkers want to add a comment box in each tab. I am thinking of creating 7 new variables for 7 tabs (and cell name will be T1_commentbox, T2_commentbox etc).

Comment: If the data type is set to number in database, will  database read the contents in the commentbox?  This is different to my previous question as I want both short texts/numbers to be stored in the same column in database...Is this possible to do by using a certain data type so both numbers/strings can be stored? @braX

Comment: These are all great questions, but they are not specific to this question. If you have other questions, you can create new topics about them. Please limit your questions to one per topic. Keep in mind that the topics are intended to help other people in the future as well as you and not designed to walk you thru entire design concepts step by step.